# can someone explain to what this line of code does? It is about Linked Lists

Tags: c++, class, operators, nodes, singly-linked-list

i was given the following declaration by my professor and i have a couple functions i need to write based on this declaration of LinkedList but i am stuck on determining what a couple lines of code does. i understand everything pretty much up to these lines;

```
friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const LinkedList &ll )
{
LinkedList::Node *current;
for (current = ll.head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
os << current->data << " ";
return os;
}
```

here is the complete code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class LinkedList
{
public:
LinkedList() { head = NULL; } // default constructor makes an empty list
// functions to aid in debugging
// -----------------------------
friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const LinkedList &ll );
void insertHead( int item );
private:
class Node // inner class for a linked list node
{
public:
Node( int item, Node *n ) // constructor
int data; // the data item in a node
Node *next; // a pointer to the next node in the list
};
Node *head; // the head of the list
};
friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const LinkedList &ll )
{
LinkedList::Node *current;
for (current = ll.head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
os << current->data << " ";
return os;
}
void LinkedList::insertHead( int item ) // insert at head of list
{
head = new Node( item, head );
}
LinkedList::Node::Node( int item, Node *n ) {Node::data = item; next = n;}
```

---

ps. can someone also please explain what friend operator does, coz i have never used it before?

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/) is your friend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const LinkedList &ll )
```

overloads the "insertion operator", so you can display your list using the common C++ syntax:

```
std::cout << mylist;
```

The line above is equivalent to:

```
operator<<(std::cout, mylist)
```

The first argument is of type `std::ostream`, and the second one of type `LikedList`.

The operator needs to be a friend since it (probably) needs access to private/protected members.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for more details on operator overloading.

Comment: @zeDante And for the other part of the code in question, you might want to read up on how a `for` loop works. See [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html) for some info on that subject. I'll leave the linked list portion of that line of code to you since the class subject appears to be linked lists.

Comment: thank you soo much this really makes alot more sense now. one final question just for clarification, do the line os<<current -> data << " " a way of saying 'cout'

Comment: yes, `os` represents the input stream of the function, passed by reference. So when you say `cout << my_list`, `cout` is being passed to `operator<<` as the first argument. Inside the function it is referred as `os`. Note also that it is not necessarily to use `cout`, you can as well use a file `out_file << my_list`, and the content will be send to the file, since the latter is also an `ostream`. That's the beauty of using inheritance and writing a function that works for the base of a well designed hierarchy.